# Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle for Infinite Matrices (Mathematical Proof and Physical Significance)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Strang talks about Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle for infinite matrices in his text on "An Introduction to Linear Algebra" (5th Edition, Section 6.1, Page 303):

*Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle for Infinite Matrices*:

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are infinite matrices satisying
$$
A B - B A = I \tag{1}
$$
with
$$
A = A^T, \ \ B = - B^T \tag{2}
$$

Then Heisenberg's uncertainty principle says that
$$
\left( {\Vert A x \Vert \over \Vert x \Vert} \right) \left( {\Vert B x \Vert \over \Vert x \Vert} \right) \geq {1 \over 2}   \tag{3}
$$

Strang: "It is impossible to get the position error and momentum error both very small."

I am trying to understand this result and also establish the inequality (3).

(I have not worked with infinite matrices before and I'm currently reading a Springer Book on Infinite Matrices by P.N. Shivakumar, K C Sivakumar and Yang Zhang. This book deals with both finite and infinite matrices and discusses in depth about solutions of the system $A x = B$, where $A$ and $B$ are infinite matrices.)

Following the outline given by G. Strang, we get
$$
\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2 = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} =  \mathbf{x}^T I \mathbf{x} 
$$

Using (1), we get
$$
\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2 = \mathbf{x}^T (A B - B A) \mathbf{x} =
\mathbf{x}^T (A^T B + B^T A) \mathbf{x} = < A x, B x > + < B x, A x > \tag{4}
$$

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get
$$
|< A \mathbf{x}, B \mathbf{x} > | \leq \Vert A \mathbf{x} \Vert \Vert B \mathbf{x} \Vert \ \ \mbox{and} \ \
|< B \mathbf{x}, A \mathbf{x} > | \leq \Vert B \mathbf{x} \Vert \Vert A \mathbf{x} \Vert \tag{5}
$$

From (4) and (5), we get
$$
\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2 \leq 2 \Vert A \mathbf{x} \Vert \Vert B \mathbf{x} \Vert 
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\Vert A \mathbf{x} \Vert \Vert B \mathbf{x} \Vert \geq { \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2 \over 2}
$$
or
$$
\left( {\Vert A x \Vert \over \Vert x \Vert} \right) \left( {\Vert B x \Vert \over \Vert x \Vert} \right) \geq {1 \over 2}  
$$

This is an outline of the proof, and I like to know how is $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert$ defined
in infinite dimensional space, and also why  the Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities as
stated in (5) hold true for infinite matrices. (I studied the proof only for
finite-dimensional inner-product spaces).

What is the context of the matrices $A$ and $B$ in the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle?

(I did not understand about "position error" and "momentum error").

A reference or explanations on this will be a great learning experience for me.

This topic has not been discussed before in this forum (I checked archives!)

Thank you!

Comment: The proofs of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality that I'm aware of do not make use of finite-dimensionality and thus apply to inner products over infinite dimensional spaces

Comment: As for the physical significance, that question might be better suited for the [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). That said, a detailed explanation is given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). Perhaps you should look there and ask for clarification as necessary

Comment: There is a name which I don't see here: "**Hilbert Space**" generalizing Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$. All this should be done in this space with $A,B$ operators (preferable to infinite matrices).